# bind function in JS without binding 'this' value

Tags: javascript, node.js

Saw we have a simple fn like so:

```
function run(foo, cb){
   setTimeout(() => {
      cb(null, {'val': foo, 'this': this});
   }, 400);
}
```

and we want to reuse the function, maybe with the async library:

```
async.map({

foo: run.bind(null,'foo'),
bar: run.bind(null,'bar'),
baz: run.bind(null,'baz')

}, function(err){


});
```

what I would like to do is avoid binding the "this" value in the function, and make this less verbose.

One thing we could do is this instead:

```
   function run(foo){
    return function(cb){
       setTimeout(() => {
          cb(null, {val: foo, this: this);
       }, 400);
    }
  }
```

and then have this:

```
async.map({

foo: run('foo'),
bar: run('bar'),
baz: run('baz')

}, function(err){


});
```

this is cleaner, but I think that using the bind functionality can produce more generic code, objectively, over using the latter pattern.

Does anyone know if there is a native way to call bind without binding the "this" value of a function. Or perhaps a way to implement a Function.prototype.bind() function that doesn't bind the "this" value?

Here's my attempt:

```
Function.prototype.customBind = function(){

    var self = this;
    var args1 = Array.from(arguments);

    return function(){

      var args2 = Array.from(arguments);
      self.apply(this, args1.concat(args2));
   }

};
```

in this way, we can use the dynamic value for "this"? We would use this code like so:

```
async.map({

foo: run.bindCustom('foo'),
bar: run.bindCustom('bar'),
baz: run.bindCustom('baz')

}, function(err){


});
```

Comment: No, you cannot bind the function without binding it, but you can use a custom function for [*partial application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) like you just did. However, currying `run` (your first attempt) is totally fine either.

Comment: I am surprised there is no native method for partial application that avoids binding the this value...? right?

Comment: Yes, there is none (but many functional helper libraries provide one). I guess there won't be one either, arrow functions are the usually recommended way to do this.

Comment: If you think that's true, would you mind adding an answer that demonstrates how to solve this with arrow functions? I do not follow

Comment: They want you to write `cb => run('foo', cb)` instead of `run.bindCustom('foo')` (which is not exactly equivalent, but usually easier)

Comment: I do not follow, sorry, ok nevermind I see

Comment: I don't think that works here @Bergi because then it will be bound to the this value of the outer scope, which is not what we want, right?

Comment: arrow functions don't solve the problem

Comment: or maybe I am wrong

Comment: Your `run` function does not care about its `this` value at all, which is why all solutions (even `.bind(null, …)`) work

Comment: right, but I am saying what if it did care about 'this'?

Comment: Then you'd use `cb => run.call(whatever, 'foo', cb)` (or usually, with a method: `cb => object.run('foo', cb)`), that are equivalent to `run.bind(…)`; if you cared about the `this` context that the callback itself is called with you'd have to use an ordinary function expression - but this case is so rare that it is deemed irrelevant